# how to consume a download function in web service?

Tags: c#, service, download

i'm using microsoft visual studio, c# language.
i was able to consume the upload function which allow user to choose the file to upload.
But i was unable to download the file. Is there any button similar to the upload function which using the "FileUpload" in the toolbox?

//this is part of the wsdl
`<s:element name="DownloadFile">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FName" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="DownloadFileResponse">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DownloadFileResult" type="s:base64Binary"   /> 
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element>`

//service requestor
//download
`protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text=Convert.ToBase64String(a.DownloadFile(TextBox1.Text));
    }`
//upload
`protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text=a.UploadFile(FileUpload1.FileBytes, TextBox2.Text);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do yourself using the WebClient class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx

Check the "DownloadFile" method of WebClient.

This is what you need in order to download from anywhere.